# Как вырезать лишние страницы в pdf файле средствами php?

Tags: php, pdf

Есть `PDF` файл на сервере. Необходимо отрезать от него лишние страницы. Например начиная с 3 и до конца, а то что останется, положить обратно на сервер. Реализовать это необходимо с помощью `php`. Буду благодарен если подскажите как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать метод `import()` библиотеки FPDF.

[Документация](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/the-fpdi-class/#index-2)

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('file.pdf');

//переходим по каждой странице и импортируем ее
//$pageNum - номер первой страницы
//если нужно сохранить все страницы с 3-й по последнюю, ставите `$pageNum=3`
for( $pageNum=1; $pageNo<=$pageCount; $pageNum++ )
{
    $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNum);

    // Определяем формат страницы(альбомный или книжный)
    $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

    if( $size['w']>$size['h'] )
        $pageFormat = 'L';  //альбомный
    else
        $pageFormat = 'P';  //книжный

    $pdf->addPage($pageFormat,array($size['w'],$size['h']));
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);
}

//сохраняем файл
$filename="/home/user/public_html/test.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
```